# How to remove the use of ES6 arrow function in this code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am not familiar with ES6 arrow functions and I received the code below from a vendor:

```
Highcharts.seriesType('linearregression', 'pareto', {
  name: 'Linear Regression'
}, {
  setDerivedData: function() {
    if (this.baseSeries.yData.length > 1) {
      var xValues = this.baseSeries.xData,
        yData = this.baseSeries.yData,
        mainData = this.baseSeries.data;
      var sum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        len = xValues.length,
        data, rise, gradient, intercept;
      Highcharts.each(xValues, function(x, i) {
        sum[0] += x;
        sum[1] += yData[i];
        sum[2] += x * x;
        sum[3] += x * yData[i];
        sum[4] += yData[i] * yData[i];
      });
      run = ((len * sum[2]) - (sum[0] * sum[0]));
      rise = ((len * sum[3]) - (sum[0] * sum[1]));
      gradient = run === 0 ? 0 : (rise / run);
      intercept = (sum[1] / len) - ((gradient * sum[0]) / len);
      function round(value, decimals) {
        return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
      };
      function predict(x) {
        return [mainData[x].name, round((gradient * x) + intercept, 5)];
      };
      points = xValues.map(p => predict(p));
      this.setData(points, false);
    }
  }
});
```

I wanted to put this into production today but just found out that ES6 is not supported in IE.  How can this be rewritten to remove the arrow function (the line below)?

```
      points = xValues.map(p => predict(p));
```

Comment: Use a regular function? Might make sense to at least look them up so you can see what they are (which would have also answered this question within minutes).

Comment: Paste it into a transpiler of your liking, e.g. [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/)

Comment: Id keep the ES6 syntax cause you might as well get use to using it since its the future of Javascript. Honestly, you should have a transpiler like Babel as part of your build step. Not only will it ensure that your javascript works in specific browser versions, but it will also catch syntax errors for you. If you keep the es6 syntax and use Babel, check out babel-polyfill too as you will need that to make it work inside of IE and Edge.

Comment: Sorry that question may seem trivial to those who are much more adept at Javascript than me but I was trying to hit a deadline and didn't have time to learn on the fly and experiment with different options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
points = xValues.map(function(p) { return predict(p); });
```

Comment: Thanks @phuzi, that's just what I needed.  Thanks for the quick response! BTW, I think whoever down voted the question was a bit harsh.